# Parity Ethereum node missing CLI option to display configuration setting of a running node

Tags: parity

I'm playing around with config.toml and using CLI options. Maybe I missed something, but I'm interested in executing a command by which I can exactly see what options are in effect when a Parity Ethereum node is running. This will help me fine tuning the node and when I'm experiencing issues. Preferable a CLI solution. 
Could this be delivered?

KR Rene